# iPhone 7 never shows "LTE" even on LTE network

Tags: iphone, lte, 4g

I have an iPhone 7 which I bought directly from Apple, and my SIM contract is with Three here in the UK. I have been using this phone happily since September, I had noticed the mobile data connection flips between *3G* and *4G* which I thought little of at first. I figured 3G = HSPA/+ and 4G = LTE.

However, the other week I was with a friend in the US who had recently got a 7 plus. She is with AT&T and I noticed that her phone was most often displaying *LTE* as the connection type. I thought this was odd as I had never seen this on my own iPhone 7 and had presumed that 4G meant LTE. I did a little googling and found some discussions which claimed that on iOS the 4G mean HSPA+ and 3G means regular old 3G. In this case I was double confused as my carrier, Three, supposedly has a 4G LTE network and so I should see LTE from time to time.

I understand that Three does not have an LTE-Advanced network, only regular LTE. So is this perhaps the distinction and confusion? 4G = LTE and LTE = LTE-Advanced?

Could somebody perhaps clear up what is going on? Do I need to contact my carrier to change the network connection settings on my phone? If I can make use of the iPhone 7's faster mobile data tech then I would like to as I am a very heavy data user. The reason I went with Three was for their unlimited data tariff.

EDIT:

As requested by owlswipe. A photo showing Speedtest saying the network is "Three  LTE" with the network icon at the top left saying "4G" which it did throughout the test. I am on 40th floor of a tower here so speeds aren't fantastic...

[image: Speedtest shows "Three LTE"]

Comment: Let me know if my answer solves your question or not; if not, leave a comment below it and I'll be happy to help more!

Comment: I'm pretty sure the US is the only market where HSPA+ is referred to as “4G,” due to the marketing BS we had to endure during that transition. In the rest of the world, HSPA+ has a “3G” indicator and LTE is marked as “4G.”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most carriers support LTE on just about any modern smartphone, including iPhones going back to the iPhone 5. Indeed, Three rolled out LTE [back in 2014](https://www.engadget.com/2013/09/11/three-4g-rollout-42-cities-2014/).

Your friend is correct that 4G (HSPA+) is not the same as LTE. In general, LTE has shorter range but enables significantly faster data speeds than plain old 4G (hence its name, Long Term Evolution).

To enable LTE, go to `Settings` -> `Cellular Data Options` -> `Enable LTE` and choose either `Data Only` or `Voice and Data`.

---

**More information:**

- [Manually Enabling LTE on iPhone](http://www.cultofmac.com/421369/how-and-why-to-disable-lte-on-your-iphone/) (cult of mac)
- [Difference Between 4G and LTE](https://gadgetwise.blogs.nytimes.com/2012/03/26/qa-the-need-for-speed/) (nyt gadgetwise)
- [Picture Evidence of 3 LTE](http://www.three.com.hk/website//ShowProperty//cmrep/three_care/cs/images/iphone_4g_img04e.JPG) (three support)

---

**Edit:** Based on OP's evidence, it seems that on 3 UK, LTE is referred to as 4G, so indeed the status bar will never show "LTE", just "4G", even while on a 4G-LTE network. As long as the speeds hold up to LTE-quality, you're probably getting LTE. This is likely a regional difference, determined by the language on your phone.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I have always had LTE Voice and Data enabled, and yet I have never seen my phone connect to the LTE network.

Comment: @Luke Huh. Can you check Three's signal map to make sure you're in an area where they have LTE coverage?

Comment: yep, central London, totally covered.

Comment: @Luke Can you try resetting network settings in Settings -> General -> Reset -> Reset Network Settings? You will have to reenter WiFi passwords (don't worry, nothing else will be deleted) but I think there's a decent chance it'll fix your issue.

Comment: I have tried that, I'll see if it fixes it.

Comment: After around a week of use I haven't really noticed any difference. Still no LTE.

Comment: So I just did a test using the Speedtest app, and that claimed that I am connected to Three LTE... even though the icon at the top left of my screen says 4G.

Comment: @Luke Weird! Can you add a screenshot to your post of where the Speedtest app says you're connected to LTE?

Comment: Okay I've done that.

Comment: @Luke That is—weird. I'm guessing the name of your carrier is Three LTE (not that you're necessarily on LTE). And those speeds are pretty slow. I recommend bringing your phone into the Apple Store, unless you think your problem is with Three—do you have some kind of really weird plan that wouldn't include LTE coverage?

Comment: Three includes LTE with all of their plans. Well, "4G". They don't actually ever mention LTE in marketing. The speeds are only slow because of where I am. They are much faster down on the ground. I have seen 87Mbps down and 24Mbps up before which I guess must have been LTE though I didn't see LTE in the status bar... it still said 4G. I even have a screenshot.

Comment: @Luke Oh wow that's fast. So maybe that is LTE! I don't know what to say but it sounds like you're not lacking in data speed.

Comment: I went in and spoke to somebody in a Three store. He seemed pretty confident that it was simply a regional difference, and that in the UK we call LTE 4G (which is true) so iOS displays 4G when connected to LTE. I didn't think Apple would go to the trouble with minor regional differences like that but I suppose it would make sense.

Comment: @Luke Indeed Apple does have different language settings for UK English vs US English, so this holds up. And given that your 4G speeds are so fast, it probably is LTE. I guess case closed! I'll amend my answer but you can make your own and accept that if you'd prefer.

Comment: @Luke I would be interested to see what would happen if you switched your phone's system language to US English, maybe it would start showing LTE.